# How to get GStreamer working on Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, gstreamer

I want to get GStreamer working on Android, it's GStreamer 1.0 not GStreamer SDK(it has been two years since it's last update). I download package from [this](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/android/1.5.90/) , there is a ndk-build file, I worked about Android but not NDK, I have no idea about how to build a project in Eclipse NDK by these. Could anyone can give me some tips?

Comment: It looks like they use Cerbero, and the "Building with Cerbero" manuals start with _"Are you sure you want to be doing this?"_. Can you use the .a files?

Comment: Do you mean the tutorial "Building from source using Cerbero" from GStreamer SDK? I want to build from GStreamer1.0 not GStreamerSDK, or they have same way to build?

Comment: yes, http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Building+from+source+using+Cerbero My *guess* is that they likely are similar. If you learn one, you likely will be able to use the other.

Comment: thank you, I will try. And do you have any idea about how to use http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/android/1.5.90/ package?